# Scala asInstanceOf generic type does not fail in Try

Tags: scala, generics, casting

Trying to cast a `String` to a `Double` obviously should fail:

```
scala> Try("abc".asInstanceOf[Double])
res11: scala.util.Try[Double] = Failure(java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Double)
```

However, if I define the above as a function:

```
scala> def convertAsTypeOf[T](anyValue: Any): Try[T] = Try(anyValue.asInstanceOf[T])
convertAsTypeOf: [T](anyValue: Any)scala.util.Try[T]
```

Strangely it returns Success when I try to cast a `String` to a `Double`:

```
scala> convertAsTypeOf[Double]("abc")
res10: scala.util.Try[Double] = Success(abc)
```

If I try to get the value out of Success, I get the following exception:

```
scala> convertAsTypeOf[Double]("abc").get
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
        at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToDouble(BoxesRunTime.java:119)
```

Why does this happen? Is there any way to fix this and make `asInstanceOf[T]` when it's in a generic function?

Comment: Someone should mention `import shapeless.syntax.typeable._ ; "abc".cast[Double]` for the use case.

Answer (score 4):

Because of type erasure, the type `T` is unknown at runtime, so `asInstanceOf` can't actually check the cast that it does. In fact, it compiles as a no-op. However, when the `.get` is finally done a cast is made to `Double`, and because the type is known here we can get a `ClassCastException`.

If you change `convertAsTypeOf` to use `ClassTag`:

```
def convertAsTypeOf[T](anyValue: Any)(implicit tag: ClassTag[T]): Try[T] =
  Try(tag.runtimeClass.cast(anyValue).asInstanceOf[T])
```

You will then get errors when you expect:

```
scala> convertAsTypeOf[Double]("abc")
res1: scala.util.Try[Double] = Failure(java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast java.lang.String to double)
```

The `ClassTag` represents the type `T` at runtime, allowing the value to be checked against it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. It does not work on Double or Int argument.  `scala> convertAsTypeOf[Double](32.2)
res86: scala.util.Try[Double] = Failure(java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast java.lang.Double to double)`

Answer (score 1):

The reason this happens is type erasure, which makes asInstanceOf[T] for generic T useless.  I don't know why the compiler doesn't issue any warning.

You can force the check to happen by using a ClassTag.  Something like this:

```
import reflect.ClassTag

def convertAsTypeOf[T : ClassTag](anyValue: Any): Try[T] = Try {
    anyValue match { case t: T => t }
}
```

This works because the compiler will use the implicit ClassTag in the case match if it is available (and generate a warning if it is not).

Comment: `asInstanceOf[T]` lets you regain type safety when you know something the compiler doesn't.

Comment: If `T` is erased, won’t type safety require a run-time check somewhere?  How does the compiler decide where to put that check?

Comment: It happens when you use the value as some type. In REPL, compare `val x = identity(2.0)` and `val x: Any = identity(2.0)` using `:javap -prv -`. Or `f[A](a: A) = 42.asInstanceOf[A]`, it will throw in the first case.